# Room Migration if we don't know start version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am writing migrations for android app just like below.

```
val MIGRATION_5_6: Migration = object : Migration(5, 6) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE survey_grid " + " ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER NOT NULL")
            }
        }

    val MIGRATION_6_7: Migration = object : Migration(6, 7) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE survey_grid " + " ADD COLUMN new_column_2 INTEGER NOT NULL")
        }
    }

    val MIGRATION_1_7: Migration = object : Migration(1, 7) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE survey_grid " + " ADD COLUMN new_column_3 INTEGER NOT NULL")
        }
    }
```

Now my current version is 7 but **I don't know the current verion** of application with user. There can be multiple combinations from  **start version** to **current version=7**.

How can I write migration which gives me user **old version** of app and new version as It is done in **onUpgrade** function of **SQLiteDatabaseHelper**? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Read This](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) . Its bit Old but i thing Migration concept is same till now . I short Room will Handle a jump in version .

Comment: @ADM, I have gone through the article but it does not indicate how to handle the above scenario. consider a scenario, user tried to install app and migration started from version 1 and at version 3, migration stopped for some reason, now my migration should support from 3 to 7 after relaunch rather version 1 to 7, hope this is clearing the concern. in SQLiteOpenHelper, I handled this situation like if oldVersion < 3 do this migration, if oldVersion < 6 do this and so on.